# find number of consecutive identical rows in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

suppose I want to do something similar as rle for pandas data frame:

```
In [247]:  import pandas as pd

In [248]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],[3, 4],[3,4],[3,4],[5,6]])

In [249]: df
Out[249]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  3  4
3  3  4
4  1  2
```

I would like to get an output which tells me that the first row is different to the second, the second is 3 times repeated and then the forth is again repeated only once. So an output like that

```
In [250]: (1, 3, 1)
```

What is a pythonic way to achieve this (and fast) in python 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way. I would call this pythonic but not pandonic.

```
from itertools import groupby

dups = [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(zip(df[0], df[1]))]
```

Comment: I prefer the term "Pandtastic" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using `join` and `value_counts`

```
s=df.astype('str').apply(','.join,1).value_counts(sort=False)
s
Out[275]: 
1,2    1
3,4    3
5,6    1
dtype: int64
```

With tuple

```
tuple(s.tolist())
Out[278]: (1, 3, 1)
```

Comment: My idea was to go with `tuple` and same approach but got `[1, 1, 3]` as a result. Your approach yielded the same result as mine.

Comment: @zipa Aha :-)   that is the way to go  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to keep it `pandas` so this is what you can do using pandas only:

```
values = df.apply(tuple, axis=1)
counts = values.value_counts()
result = values.drop_duplicates().map(counts)
tuple(result)
#(1, 3, 1)
```